# domain name registration in route53

Tags: amazon-route53

I have purchased a domain from aws console (ex:inetglobal.net)
then i have created bucket sky.inetglobal.net and kept a index.html file inside of it. I have enabled website hosting for this bucket.Now trying to map bucket endpoint with in route53 by creating A record

sky.inetglobal.net.  A ALIAS s3-website-us-east-1.amazonaws.com

So now if i will type sky.inetglobal.net in browser then content of html file should be visble. But it is not resolve to subdomain sky.inetglobal.net
can any one help in this??

Comment: Can you please tell me how you initially created your Hosted Zone? You created it using sky.inetglobal.net or inetglobal.net?

Comment: inetglobal.net....................................................

Answer (score 0):

Try having another A record for sub-domain with the same s3 endpoint and it will work.

Comment: how can we create same subdomain with A record?? it will conflict..is nt??